# silverstrip Object->__call(): the method 'fortemplate' does not exist on 'HasManyList', or the method is not public

Tags: php, silverstripe, has-many, silverstripe-4

I am getting this error in front end template my template file is empty,
when I try to `addFieldToTab`. I think `$has_many` variable has problem.

My Code is as below :

```
class ProductsPage extends Page
{
  private static $has_many = array (
    'ProductCategories' => 'ProductCategories',
  );

    public function getCMSFields() {
       $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
       $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', GridField::create(
            'ProductCategories',
            'Category',
            $this->ProductCategories(),
            GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
        ));
       return $fields;
   }
}
```

Error :

> [User Error] Uncaught Exception: Object->__call(): the method
>   'fortemplate' does not exist on 'HasManyList', or the method is not
>   public.

PasteBin URL : https://pastebin.com/YZJn3a4t

when i am remove `$has_many` variable it work perfect. in my front end template is empty.

how to fix this error i do not understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $has_many array *value* should be in singular form, whereas it's *key* is plural.

Using your example this should be 'Category' => 'ProductCategories' (I got this from what you're doing with the GridField below).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks , i changed $has_many array key name and it is work.
'Category' => 'ProductCategories'.

Comment: There is an actual definition on how to declare relations "Relations are built through static array definitions on a class, in the format <relationship-name> => <classname>." in https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/relations/ . E.g value references the actual class